# How do I import snapshots running a full node from Ubuntu 16?

Tags: node, snapshots

I have followed these instructions to start running the tezos mainnet (up to "git checkout mainnet".

https://www.reddit.com/r/tezos/comments/9goyr2/setup_instructions_for_mainnet_node_ubuntu_1804/

Then I have gone ahead and downloaded the full node via this git repo:
https://github.com/Phlogi/tezos-snapshots

What are the next steps to restore/import the node from the snapshot?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to run `./tezos-node snapshot import FILE.full` (you may need to specify your `--data-dir path/to/dir` if not using the default one).

For more details, the snapshot documentation can be found here: http://tezos.gitlab.io/user/snapshots.html.

Comment: Also the link you gave me on the tezos  gitlab website is now downloading the dune protocol I think, the folder has dune workspace and dune text file in it....

Comment: tezos-node: internal error, uncaught exception:
            (Invalid_argument "Bigarray.create: negative dimension")
            Raised at file "src/core/lwt.ml", line 2998, characters 20-29
            Called from file "src/unix/lwt_main.ml", line 26, characters 8-18
            Called from file "src/bin_node/node_snapshot_command.ml", line 70, characters 10-26
            Called from file "cmdliner_term.ml", line 25, characters 19-24
            Called from file "cmdliner.ml", line 26, characters 27-34
            Called from file "cmdliner.ml", line 117, characters 32-39

Comment: Finally got it! you have to change the file name, tezos-node folder has to be set up and you have to unpack the zipped node, and you have to do it with unxz command... I will write in depth instructions later

Comment: "dune" is the build system used in Tezos (see https://github.com/ocaml/dune). It is not related to anything else.
The node handles only uncompressed snapshots. Thus, depending on the format of the snapshot you have downloaded, you may need to do other manipulations. The next update of snapshots will give a better error when providing incompatible files :)

Comment: Awesome! Got it all figured out.  Thank you everyone for your help.